# Как повторным нажатие на input radio удалять подставленную ссылку

Tags: javascript, html

имеется вот такой скрипт, при нажатие на radio страница перезагружается и добавляет target к ссылке.

Как сделать, так что бы при повторном нажатие на радио, добавленный таргет к ссылку убирался, c перезагрузкой страницы

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('label input[value=link1]').on('click', function() {
        // alert('write here code');
        window.location.href = '?link1';
    });
    $('label input[value=link2]').on('click', function() {
        // alert('write here code 2');
        window.location.href = '?link2';
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<label> <input type="radio" name="proview" value="link1"> Text one</label>
<br>
<label> <input type="radio" name="proview" value="link2"> Text two</label>
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

думаю алгоритм должен быть таким:

1. после загрузки страницы получить параметр `window.location.href`
2. из полученного href извлечь нужные линки (зависит от того, что именно вы после ? в href передаете - одно название или несколько)
3. удалить (или скрыть) элементы

к примеру

```
$(`label input[value={link}]`).hide()
```